# How I can specify directories in war file?

Tags: java, deployment, servlets, jboss, directory

I am new to servlet . I use the following code in servlet.then deployed to Jboss 4.1 . backup_database_configuration_location is location of properties file.But it can't be find. how I can specify directories in war file ?
Thanks all in advance

```
try {
  backupDatabaseConfiguration = new Properties();
  FileInputStream backupDatabaseConfigurationfile = new FileInputStream(backup_database_configuration_location));
  backupDatabaseConfiguration.load(backupDatabaseConfigurationfile);
  backupDatabaseConfigurationfile.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Exception while loading backup databse configuration ", e);
  throw new ServletException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is placed in the **webcontent**, then use [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/file.properties"));
```

The `getServletContext()` method is inherited from `HttpServlet`. Just call it as-is inside servlet.

If it is placed in the **classpath**, then use [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.properties");
```

The difference with [`Class#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is that you're not dependent on the classloader which loaded the class (which might be a different one than the thread is using, if the class is actually for example an utility class packaged in a JAR and the particular classloader might not have access to certain classpath paths).

Answer (score 1):

Where is your properties file located? Is it directly somewhere in your hard drive, or packaged in a JAR file?

You can try to retrieve the file using the [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
configuration = new Properties();
configuration.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(backup_database_configuration_location));
```

(or course, replace `MyClass` by your current class name)

Comment: This is the approach I use, though there are some things to note:
a) You should close the InputStream after the .load method.
b) From a class, the getResourceAsStream will be relative to that ClassLoader. Meaning that if your file is located at /WEB-INF/classes/com/example/config.properties , you will have to pass "/com/example/config.properties" into getResourceAsStream.

Comment: @Clinton For the point a: Yes, of course. I didn't write the `try { } catch` block neither ;)